# error at logging a side-page html - autocomplete item not working

Tags: html, google-apps-script, autocomplete

I'm working on a project, where the user will use side-bar html page, as a form to update a sheet (very basic operation).
I'm having issue with the autocomplete part.

I'm a beginner to code html with google apps script, so please let me know if you don't have enough information.

The script is supposed to get names from a google sheets, and populate it to the autocomplete item.

I followed a tutorial doing practically the same operation, but based on a web app using a google spreadsheet ==> this one worked perfectly for me. 
The challenge is now into adapting it to a sidebar page on google sheet ==> does not work at the moment.

I've been struggling for hours and trying different options, so here is :
- What I made on gs page :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var shEmployees = ss.getSheetByName("Employes");

var colEmploye_nomPrenom=1;
var colEmploye_barcode=colEmploye_nomPrenom+1;
var colEmploye_mail=colEmploye_barcode+1;
var colEmploye_metier=colEmploye_mail+1;

function loadBasicForm(){
   var tmp=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("basicHtmlForm");
   var html = tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    html.setTitle("Test");
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);

}//function loadBasicForm(){


function getUnactiveEmployees(){

  var ws=shEmployees;
  var values= ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),colEmploye_metier).getValues();
  var options={};

  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){    
    var name=values[i][colEmploye_nomPrenom-1];
    var job=values[i][colEmploye_metier-1];
    var testUnactive_OK=job=="Désactivé";
    if (testUnactive_OK){
      options[name]=null;            
    }//if (testUnactive_OK){        
  }//for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++){

  Logger.log (options);//returns  {employee1=null, employee8=null, employee3=null, employee9=null, employee5=null, employee10=null, employee7=null, employee6=null, employee11=null, employee4=null, employee2=null}
  return options;

}
```

What I made on html page :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>      
      <base target="_top">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><!--Import Google Icon Font-->      
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"><!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->      
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    </head>

    <body>

       <div class="container">        
          <div class="row">   
             <div class="input-field col s12">
               <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
               <input type="text" id="searchedEmployee" class="autocomplete" required><!-- ISSUE AT FILLING IT  -->
               <label for="searchedEmployee">Spell a Name</label>
             </div>   
          </div><!-- END ROW -->            
       </div ><!-- END CONTAINER -->    

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script>    

      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateEmployees).getUnactiveEmployees();              
      });         
      function populateEmployees(employees){  
        var autocomplete = document.getElementById('searchedEmployee');
        var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, { data:employees }); 
      }     

      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

At this point, the side-page is displayed, but nothing is suggested at typing, for example : "emp" for "employeeX" expected with the "getUnactiveEmployees" list.

EDIT : 
My issue is not about displaying - that does displaying. 
What I cannot do, is to allow the script to autocomplete the item "searchedEmployee". I guess there is an error on this part :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {    
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateEmployees).getUnactiveEmployees();              
          });
```

Do you have any idea of what I did wrong ?

Many thanks !

Comment: What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function loadBasicForm(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('basicHtmlForm').setTitle('Test'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my question so that it may be clearer on my explanation and expectations :p I tried your suggestion, but the result is the same : displaying OK - autocompleting not OK. with my update, maybe you think about another lead to investigate ?